# extractData of SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor expects SqlRowSet as return type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-boot

I am using the below code to extract data from the resultset. I have been getting a compilation error:

> The return type is incompatible with SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(ResultSet) Change return type of extractData(...) to SqlRowSet

```
package uk.co.company.security.SQL;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor;

import uk.co.company.security.User;

public class UserExtractor extends SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor {
private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserExtractor.class);

public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

    return null;
}
}
```

As per my research [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.html#extractData(java.sql.ResultSet)), it should have been OK. This has been working for me before as well with spring mvc. I am now moving my code to Spring Boot. Nothing major has really changed. Wondering if it has anything to do with Spring Boot or Have I messed up my existing code.

Comment: I doubt that that code worked because, as the error states, the return types don't match. I suspect initially you implemented `ResultSetExtractor` instead of extending `SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor` (which is an implementation of the `ResultSetExtractor`).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am 100% sure it worked the way I have mentioned in the post. However, I have now tried to implement using `ResultSetExtractor` instead of extending `SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor`. That seems to work for now, unless I get a better answer for this.

Comment: Also the documentation you point at is an old version of Spring 2.5. If you use a more recent version the `ResultSetExtractor` is actually `ResultSetExtractor<T>` so it is generic and for the `SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor` that is `ResultSetExtractor<SqlRowSet>`. So if you also upgraded spring it is logical it fails. Next to that although it worked, it wasn't the way it was supposed to be.

Comment: @M.Deinum That makes sense now. I am now using Spring 4.3.7 and have used [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of extending [`SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.html) you should implement [`ResultSetExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html). Which you should have done in the first place, the `SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor` is used by the `JdbcTemplate` for the [`queryForRowSet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.html) methods and shouldn't be extended.

As of Spring 3.0 the `ResultSetExtrator` is generic and reads `ResultSetExtractor<T>` and for the `SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor` it results in `ResultSetExtractor<SqlRowSet>` then when overriding the method like you do you will get a compilation exception as `Object` != `SqlRowSet`.

In short implement `ResultSetExtractor` as it was intended to.

```
public UserExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<User> {

    public User extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException { ... }

}
```